Laravel 10 - CSRF API request
I have this js code on the updated Laravel 5.7 -> Laravel 10. On the old version, this worked perfectly fine, however, here as soon as this js is started, when it is called, it gets damaged and stolen, or what to call it, the CSRF token, when it is no longer possible to use, for example token for logging in or to any form. I don't know how to solve this at all.
function pollActiveEvent() { var locale = localStorage.getItem('selectedLanguage') || 'default_locale';

    $.ajax({
        url: '/get-active-event-translations',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { locale: locale, _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}' },
        success: function(response) {
            updateActiveEvent(response);
            setTimeout(pollActiveEvent, 5000);
        },
        error: function() {
            console.error("Nepodařilo se provést požadavek na aktivní event.");
            setTimeout(pollActiveEvent, 5000);
        }
    });
}

pollActiveEvent();`


I tried to delete the CSRF token, grant an exception in the Middleware (VerifyCsrfToken), of course, when the script was turned off, everything ran as it should). As soon as any query is made, during which the page is not refreshed, damage will occur.


Have you ever thought about adding meta tag to blade element?
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

function pollActiveEvent() {
    var locale = localStorage.getItem('selectedLanguage') || 'default_locale';
    var csrfToken = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

    $.ajax({
        url: '/get-active-event-translations',
        type: 'GET',
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrfToken },
        data: { locale: locale },
        success: function(response) {
            updateActiveEvent(response);
            setTimeout(pollActiveEvent, 5000);
        },
        error: function() {
            console.error("Failed to request active event.");
            setTimeout(pollActiveEvent, 5000);
        }
    });
}

pollActiveEvent();


Hello,  i have in master.blade.php.  This will happen with your solution too. In short, when this function is called, the login to the website is no longer functional (respectively, absolutely all requests start receiving err 419). Couldn't the reason also be that I have these routes in web.php and not in api.php?
